# Federated Authentication in Sitecore 9.3 does not create new permanent user

Tags: federated-authentication

Federated authentication is successful and changes the user profiles in the sitecore backend, but it does not create a new user, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set "isPersistentUser" setting for this federated authentication so that Sitecore will create virtual users that can be used/refer in future visits.

If that is not set, Sitecore will only create a temp user (as virtual user) and will remove after the user session expires.

Refer following Sitecore document for more information on "isPersistentUser" setting.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/configure-federated-authentication.html#UUID-d19e2e29-ba2f-6382-82b3-b70d005023ef_id__Configure_virtual_and

Comment: The setting is already given, I will look at the following document.

Comment: Its because of the CreateUniqueUsername, it has changed in 9.3, dint find a solution yet, but I can confirm that it is the issue